# Ubuntu 14.04 can't connect to wired internet after ejecting and returning network cable

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 a month ago, on a Lenovo T460p laptop.
In the last 2 weeks, I have this problem:
After ejecting the network cable from it's socket (say, when I take my laptop from work to home or vice versa), and returning it, I have no internet connection.
I already checked in Ubuntu's "Network connections", under "Ethernet" - I CAN see there "Wired connection 1" (which is the connection I normally use).
When I check ifconfig, under "eth0" I get:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:5b:76:0b:7a:2e  
          inet addr:10.10.2.51  Bcast:10.10.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ca5b:76ff:fe0b:7a2e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:53298155 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13985782 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:75752971902 (75.7 GB)  TX bytes:1333847053 (1.3 GB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:f2200000-f2220000
```

The only way to get wired connection again is to restart the laptop each time it happens. Any suggestion for what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to RESTART Networking on your machine to reset/reconfigure your broken connection.  Many hacks depend on breaking the connection then finding an open, hung, app to come into your box and gain control with the attributes of that app.  The Linux kernel was upgraded to "hang" broken connections to stop this.

Bring up a terminal window and using "sudo", or "su" (to become Root, if you have set a Root PW) and try: networking restart Enter

You may need to go to the spot (using the cd command), or explicitly type in the Path to the spot where your network is initialised (usually in /etc/init.d).  Type in the command that runs the network initialisation and the keyword "restart" and press Enter.

Often, simply issuing the command "sudo ifup -e network device name" will do the trick.  In the terminal, type in ifup -help or ifup --h or networking -help for information on the specific parameters required as arguments to the networking or ifup (or ifdown) script commands.

The same can be done using the "ifconfig" command, but is far more involved.  Mainly "ifconfig" is a quick way to check your network status.  Type "route", w/o arguments to see the current route and if your Gateway, DNS, port, etc. are correctly configured.

The networking and ifup script commands run automatically on reboot - which is what you are doing now, but work just fine without having to pretend you are on an M$ OS and completely shut down every time.

Cheers!

fudoki